# Weird kibana error - invalid code -- missing end-of-block

Tags: elasticsearch-5, kibana-5, metricbeat

I just started seeing this error on my `kibana` server :

```
read err { Error: invalid code -- missing end-of-block at 
InflateRaw.zlibOnError (zlib.js:153:15) errno: -3, code: 
'Z_DATA_ERROR' }
```

There is no helpful information in the corresponding logs :

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-01-22T13:46:34Z","tags": 
["license","info","xpack"],"pid":17310,"message":"Imported license 
information from Elasticsearch for the [monitoring] cluster: mode: 
basic | status: active"}
```

However, in the browser there is an error:  `Kibana server is not ready yet`. 
I have no idea how to tackle this!

**UPDATE**

I have seen additional error in elasticsearch logs that might suggest the cause of failure :

`[2019-01-24T11:15:47,216][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataIndexTemplateService] [cloudraid01] adding template [.management-beats] for index patterns [.management-beats]`

This seems to be related to `metricbeats`.